# Font-awesome disappears after refresh for all ie browsers ie11,ie10,ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome

I know it seems this question has been asked before, but the solutions I've found are for IE8 only.

We are using **Font Awesome 4.1.0** and **Bootstrap v3.0.3** in our project. If we load the page for the very first time all the icons render properly. When we reload page in Internet Explorer using Ctrl + R, they disappear.

This issue is occurring for all IE versions we've tested, including IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was on IE with https in all the request one header related to no-catch pragma was coming extra and that header was causing issue in loading font.

following code was added to context.xml file to fix this issue.

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator" 7
        disableProxyCaching="false" />
</Context>
```

And that context.xml file was kept in our ROOT folder.

Comment: could u help me, where to place this context.xml file

Comment: @MPPNBD It goes in the root of your site files