# font awesome icon is not appearing in IE 11, but showing in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer-11, font-awesome

I am new to font-awesome icons. I have one page in which there is a filter where user can search the data. I have added font awesome icon just before the search link (as per below screenshot), I can see this icon in all the browsers except IE 11. The funny thing is I have this icon in other pages also and I can see it in IE 11, but I cannot see this icon on this (as per below screenshot) page only.

Here is the screenshot from IE 11:

[image]

Here is the screenshot from chrome:

[image]

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue, I solved it by adding this meta tag as the **FIRST** tag in `<head>`:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Also, according to the [official documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-hosting-fonts-on-my-server-and-icons-dont-show-up), check the following:

> **For Internet Explorer**: you don't serve files with `no-store` option in Cache-control header (Ref: #6454);
>   **For Internet Explorer and HTTPS**: you don't serve files with `no-cache` option in Pragma header.

Answer (score 13):

IE has an issue with `@font-face`s being delivered with the HTTP-Header `Pragma=no-cache`. You can see it recorded on the issue tracker [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/928481/)

Unfortunately the issue is marked as not resolvable but there are some workarounds. The one that worked for me was using a servlet filter that avoids the Pragma header being set.

Other solutions that not worked for me:

[Font-awesome disappears after refresh for all ie browsers ie11,ie10,ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433294/font-awesome-disappears-after-refresh-for-all-ie-browsers-ie11-ie10-ie9)

[Font awesome icons becomes invisible in IE after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645046/font-awesome-icons-becomes-invisible-in-ie-after-refresh)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning here that IE does not cache when the "Vary" header is present. So you may need to remove that header in addition to removing the Pragma / Cache-Content: no-cache header. https://jakearchibald.com/2014/browser-cache-vary-broken/

Comment: FYI the original MS Connect link is dead because MS Connect is dead. This appears to be a reference to the issue on the issue tracker https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/928481/

As you can see it is marked as "WONT FIX".

There's also this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135282/font-face-wont-load-via-https-in-ie

Answer (score 6):

From IE console try to run following script

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />');
```

If it work then try to import it CDN instead of storing it locally.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, it might be your Internet Explorer settings that prevent the browser from downloading fonts. This was the case on one of our tightly secured servers.

Try these steps:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Internet Options
3. Under Security tab, click on Custom Level...
4. Scroll down to Downloads and make sure the Font Download is Enabled

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring MVC with Spring Security, Spring Security automatically adds no cache headers and so causes font-awesome to break on IE11.

(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control)

I solved the issue by adding a `ResourceHandler` in my `WebMvcConfiguration` for font-awesome configured to allow the browser to cache the fonts.

```
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry )
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/")
            .setCachePeriod(31556926);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same Issue and I just added the following Link in the Tag and it worked.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If apache server is serving Font files, addthe following entries to the httpd.conf or .htaccess in .

## To set right mime-types for font files, add this lines to config:

```
 AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
 AddType font/truetype .ttf
 AddType font/opentype .otf
 AddType font/opentype .woff
 AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```

## To update font files headers, This fix perfectly worked to render Font Icons in IE Browsers.

```
<LocationMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
   Header unset Cache-Control
   Header unset no-store
</LocationMatch >
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my font-icons in IIS: Add a web.config to your font directory with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Pragma" value="none" /> 
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Okay. Will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution, in our application we need no-store and no-cache headers for security reasons (added through web.config in root project).  Then in fonts folder, we added new web.config with following instructions:         <remove name="Cache-control" /><remove name="Pragma" /> which fixed our issue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisGheen could you please cite your source? I haven't found a reference where "none" is a valid value for "pragma". See: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with font awesome. I added a custom httpmodule in my .net application.

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(Context_EndRequest);
        }
        protected void Context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            if (string.Compare(HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser, "InternetExplorer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                response.Headers.Set("Pragma", "none");
            }
        }
    }
```

And registered the module in web.config.

```
<system.webserver>
    <modules>
          <add type="MyHttpModule, Culture=neutral" name="MyHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webserver>
```

It solved the issue.

Comment: System.Web.HttpException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
  Source=MyModule
  StackTrace:
   at MyModule.MyHttpModule.Context_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in T:\Websites\MyModule\MyModule\MyModule.cs:line 27

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Font Awesome 4.7 and IE 11. I fixed it by adding the following meta info in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

We recently had this issue serving Font Awesome font files from our Rails application. The confusion was that we weren't passing `Pragma` or `Cache-control` response headers - so the previous answers in this post were a bit confusing.

To summarize - this issue is caused by these two conditions:

1. The request is being initiated from `font-face`, over an HTTPS connection (critical for re-producing this bug locally).
2. The `Pragma` header has the value `no-cache` OR in our case, we're serving everything gzipped, and the `Vary` header is passed with a value other than `Accept-Encoding`.

We fixed this by adding the following to our Rack::CORS config:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'

        # Setting Vary to Accept-Encoding required or IE11 fonts will not load from local cache
        resource('*.eot',
                 headers: :any,
                 credentials: false,
                 methods: [:get],
                 vary: ['Accept-Encoding'])
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. My technology stack is Spring boot 2.0 and Angular 8.
This issue occurs only when you try to refresh the page over HTTPS on IE 11.

The problem is, the browser (IE 11) expects Cache-Control max-age. You need to set this header for static resources.
To resolve this issue set the following property in application.property file.

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=14400
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was corrupted .eot font file.  I had generated new one ( + new .css styles) and it fixed the problem. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, searched everywhere and no luck. It appears it was due to  Microsoft cumulative Security update which stopped loading Fonts/Images especially  :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486474/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-february-12-2019

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4491113/cumulative-update-for-internet-explorer-february-19-2019

To fix it you need to install the March patch:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489873/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-march-12-2019

Answer (score 0):

For internet explorer 11, you can change your CSS like that :

```
nb-icon.menu-icon { 
                  visibility: hidden; 
                  } 
nb-icon.menu-icon::before{ 
                  visibility: visible; 
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

either of 2 solutions worked for me

1. Check whether all the below mentioned
   FontAwesome.otf
   fontawesome-webfont.eot
   fontawesome-webfont.svg
   fontawesome-webfont.ttf
   fontawesome-webfont.woff
   fontawesome-webfont.woff2
2. And  I deleted the version parameter, eg. ?v4.7.0 in every src of the font in the CSS and it is now working in my IE 11.