# font awesome icons are not showing up in IE browser

Tags: font-awesome

I am using font awesom eicons in my app. I used this link in my index.html.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The icons are showing in my chrome browser and also it is showing in IE browsers in other's laptops. But it is not showing in my  browser. Do I have to change any configuration or settings for my IE browser?

Comment: can some body help me on this . I am spending days to figure out this.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32628649/1493235