# Font-Awesome/Bootstrap Glyphicons not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome, video.js

I have developed a web application where I'm using `Bootstrap Glyphicons`, `Font-Awesome` along with `VideoJS` which has it's own custom set.

In 95% of the occasions they work perfectly however in the following circumstances there are problems:

- IE11
- Client behind a Bluecoat Proxy Server

The issue is that **certain** - **not all** icons do not manage to appear (for example "fa fa-send". In particular **none** of the **VideoJS** icons appear.

This happens only with `IE11` on the specific clients that are behind a corporate proxy.

Any idea what could be the cause? Could it be some sort of proxy configuration?

Comment: Do you happen to be getting a 404 error in the console when loading the font and/or css files for VideoJS? Are you loading them from your server or linking to a version hosted somewhere else?

Comment: No 404 all the files are on my server. On other browsers it works fine except on IE only in the specific environment

Comment: It's possible that something about that environment is triggering IE to use an older rendering engine that doesn't support the `::before` pseudo element that most icon fonts rely on - if you pop open IE developer tools, does it show it's using an older version to render the page?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that their browser is set to block untrusted fonts, which I think may be a default for IE. This article may help.

https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/keep-secure/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise#Turn_on_and_use_the_Blocking_untrusted_fonts_feature

Or it's the @font-face issue similar to this stackoverflow question:

[font awesome icon is not appearing in IE 11, but showing in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291414/font-awesome-icon-is-not-appearing-in-ie-11-but-showing-in-other-browsers)