# Facing Issue in Font Awesome on Internet Explorer IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, font-awesome

I am using `Font Awesome` on my site and it works fine on Chrome, Firefox etc.
But not working in Internet Explorer. Can anyone tell me why this issue arises in Internet Explorer?
Please provide me solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: I am sharing the screenshot of both the browsers.
Chrome: https://ibb.co/kdiWVe
Internet Explorer: https://ibb.co/enjoAe
Please let me know about the issue.

Comment: can you use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` ?

Comment: And possible of duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291414/font-awesome-icon-is-not-appearing-in-ie-11-but-showing-in-other-browsers]

Comment: Please share the code you're using. It's impossible to figure this out from a picture.

Comment: Tag is already present but still font awesome is not working on 
https://ibb.co/fEf9iz

Comment: Here is the code screenshot
https://ibb.co/hzrobK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a font-size issue may be you not declared font-size inside the css that's why IE not refect your font awesome try by declaring font-size. I hope your issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks it works. After declaring the font size my problem is resolved...