# FontAwsome Icons Not displaying in IE11 HTTPS URL

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

We are using FontAwsome icons v4.7.0  on our site (.Net aspx). Font files are referred from local path. On IE11 HTTPS URL font icons are not displaying on first time page load, even on page refresh [F5]. After page postback font icons are loading properly.  No issues on HTTP URL site. We have tried may ways, but nothing workout. Kindly let us know if anything needs to add/change. Thanks in advance.

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/8825

[font awesome icon is not appearing in IE 11, but showing in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291414/font-awesome-icon-is-not-appearing-in-ie-11-but-showing-in-other-browsers)

Add this meta tag as the FIRST tag in under the HTML file

```
 <head>:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

check if IE is

Some possible solutions that might help you

Comment: @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('//yourdomain.com/path/to/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  /* ... other font-face properties ... */
}