# Font-awesome Pro 5.3.1 disappears after load for all ie browsers ie11,ie10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome-5

We are using Font Awesome Pro 5.3.1, Bootstrap v3.0.2 and AngularJS v1.7.5 in our project. If we load the page all the icons disappear.

This issue is occurring for all IE versions we've tested, including IE11 and IE10.

Our website is:
https://portaldeassinaturas.com.br

But if we load the page in localhost all the icons render properly.

Comment: Can't reproduce or I don't know what to look for. Please add relevant code and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question, so we don't have to debug a remote website of which we don't even know whether it's still broken.

Comment: @GolezTrol If you test in other browser, Google Chrome for example,  you'll see all the icons render properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some other reported issues, where the **Cache-Control** `no-store` was being used with https, causing problems in IE.

If it's an ASP.NET app, try checking Web.config if it has `<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-store" />`, and try removing it or changing to `value="max-age=0"`, and see if it works.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39055984/3211332
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26594066/3211332

Comment: It works! All the icons render properly in IE11 and IE10